# Installing 'ansible[azure]' missing dependency 'msrest'

Tags: azure, ansible

When I install Azure extension with `pip install 'ansible[azure]` and try to run a playbook with `ansible-playbook playbook.yml` I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msrest'
```

And it also mentions `Failed to import the required Python library (msrestazure)`

I got this procedure from the [official ansible docs for Azure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html#requirements).

Full error here:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msrest'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (msrestazure) on DESKTOP-JL4F430's Python /home/pomatti/projects/personal/docker-swarm-cluster-with-ansible/env/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
```

Ansible version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that from ansible version `>= 2.9` collections where released and extras are being moved.

If you don't want to use Galaxy this should do the trick:

```sh
$ pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt

$ pip install 'ansible'
```